# Airflow 2 create dynamic tasks from dag run config

Tags: python, airflow

I can create dynamic tasks from list of args in such a way

```
dag = DAG("blabla")
ids = [1,2,3]

for id in ids:
    ids_to_process = PythonOperator(task_id=f"task-{id}",dag=dag)
```

But what if I want to get my ids from dag_run config, which seems to me only works to pass to the operator like this

```
"--ids", "{{ dag_run.conf['ids'] }}"
```

I want to do something like this

```
final_ids = dag.dag_run.conf['ids'] or [1,2,3]
for id in final_ids:
    ids_to_process = PythonOperator(task_id=f"task-{id}",dag=dag)
```

I know I can use Variables, but they are stored across all dag runs therefore I can't see in the past what has been executed.

Answer (score 1):

You could, yeah

Though Airflow doesn't really... erm... enjoy changing the DAGs' structure when it "reads" (scans? imports?) them too much.

Creating a number of tasks based on a fixed list (like `ids = [1,2,3]`, as you have in your first code snippet) is very easy, because that list is not going to change "suddenly", but when the number of tasks can vary in between Dag Runs... weeeeell... then no so much.

Dynamically creating tasks is not super super straightforward. As a matter of fact, it was impossible before Airflow 2.3. It is possible now, thanks to the introduction of [Dynamic Task Mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html), but (AFAIK) you'll still need a task to extract those IDs from the config and then a second task that will use the first task's return value to dynamically trigger a group of tasks.

```
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task

with DAG(
        'SO-77345338',
        start_date=datetime(year=2023, month=10, day=23),
        catchup=False,
        schedule_interval=None,

) as dag:
    @task
    def fetch_ids(**context):
        return (context['dag_run'].conf.get('my_ids') or "").split()

    @task
    def test_fn(my_id):
        print(f"Hello {my_id}")


    test_fn.expand(my_id=fetch_ids())
```

Now, to test, let's say you trigger that DAG by running in the CLI

```
 airflow dags trigger 'SO-77345338' --conf '{"my_ids":"1 3 5"}'
```

In your config you have a string containing your `my_ids` parameter in the shape `"1 3 5"` (something easily splittable).

The `fetch_ids` task would split that string into the list `["1", "3", "5"]` and return it. Then the `test_fn` task will be expanded into three task instances, one for `id` "1", another for `id` "3" and another one for `id` "5"

[image]

And, for instance, the logs for one of those three tasks would show:
[image]

Also, I'd recommend you take a look into [Airflow Params](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/params.html#params). Maybe they provide a bit more human friendly interface?